# char sequence by length and array

Tags: java, sequences

i need to find how much sequences of $ in the beginnig ,$ in the center ,and $ in the end of len that the user is get in to the system (input) with whis function :

```
public static boolean isSequence$$$(char arr[],int len){
  double x = (len/2);
  int y =(int)(x);
  if(len % 2 == 0){
    return false;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr.length - i >= len){
      if(arr[i] == '$' && arr[i+y] == '$' && arr[i+(len-1)] == '$' ){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

and i do this but it is not working :

```
public static int NumOfSequences$$$(char arr[]){
  int count = 0;
  int j = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(isSequence$$$(arr,j)){
      count++;
      j++;
    }
    j++;
  }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  char arr[] = new char[9];
  arr[0] = '$';
  arr[1] = '2';
  arr[2] = '$';
  arr[3] = '4';
  arr[4] = '$';
  arr[5] = '8';
  arr[6] = '$';
  arr[7] = '7';
  arr[8] = '$';
  System.out.println(NumOfSequences$$$(arr));
}
```

Comment: Shalom.  Welcome to SO.  What is not working?  Please be specific with example input and expected output.

Comment: this is not exactly input its the arr in the main

Comment: expected output is 4

Comment: `arr[i+(len-1)]` can never work.  Consider `len` == 10, `i` == 9; you'll be looking at item 18 of a array of size 10.